# Increase marker pose accuracy (mainly rotation) using AR Foundation in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, ar-foundation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfAnN.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8TJi.jpg)

I'm developing an application using AR Foundation and Unity to show equipment identification in three-dimensional space. From the reading of a marker (and its position and rotation) I determine the virtual objects that must be instantiated and their positions in space.

The problem: The precision with which I determine the rotation of the marker greatly affects the positioning of the objects, mainly those farthest from the marker and with each reading there is a variation beyond what is acceptable in determining the rotation of the marker.

I'm looking for suggestions to approach the problem, either to improve the accuracy of the marker's pose or even more suitable methods for synchronizing the virtual space with the real one.

Additional data:
Position tolerance: +-0.3 meter
Maximum distance between marker and instanced objects: 50 meters
Android app.
I'm able to do 3d models for the spaces where I want to instantiate the virtual objects.

Attempts:
Aligning the rotation of the pose obtained from the marker so that it is at least pointing upwards in the real world (which would help a lot) but still not successful. Everything I've tried seems to depend on the device's home position.

Area target seems like the best approach, but I'm not able to do 3d scans. In addition, there is no such tool in AR Foundation.